# Fill extern std::array fileds one by one

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code

```
   //Block.h
    enum class BlockType : uint8_t {
    BlockType_Air = 0,
    BlockType_Default = 1,
    BlockType_Grass = 2,
    BlockCount
};

struct BlockTextureData {
    std::string top;
    std::string bottom;
    std::string left;
    std::string right;
    std::string front;
    std::string back;
};

extern std::unordered_map<BlockType, BlockTextureData*> BlockTextures;

   //Block.cpp
std::unordered_map<BlockType, BlockTextureData*> BlockTextures = {
    {BlockType::BlockType_Default, new BlockTextureData{"UV","UV","UV","UV","UV", "UV"}},
    {BlockType::BlockType_Grass, new BlockTextureData{"GrassTop","GrassBottom","GrassSide","GrassSide","GrassSide", "GrassSide"}}
};
```

Issue is the map is accessed thousands of times whitc causes it to rack up quite a performance cost, as its makes itself a bout 20% of the runtime of the given functions its in. I head you can use enum values as keys for arrays, so i wanted to replace std::unordered_map with std::array. But when i tried to populate the array i got error that its incomplete.

The thing is all enum values dont need a corresbonding object in BlockTexturers and can be null. So i would like to define the values one by one. Is there a way to do this ?

my attempt

```
//block.h
extern std::array<BlockTextureData*, static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockCount)> BlockTextures;

//block.cpp
std::array<BlockTextureData*, static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockCount)> BlockTextures[static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockType_Default)] = new BlockTextureData{"UV","UV","UV","UV","UV", "UV"};

std::array<BlockTextureData*, static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockCount)> BlockTextures[static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockType_Grass)] = new BlockTextureData{"GrassTop","GrassBottom","GrassSide","GrassSide","GrassSide", "GrassSide"};
```

Comment: "I heard you can use enum values as keys for arrays" - where did you hear that? Array don't have keys.

Comment: @ThomasWeller bad wording, i meant indexing.

Comment: The question shows code that works, and asks about a modification that doesn't work. Show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: I think the point is that the code above (in block.cpp) is at namespace scope, where it certainly doesn't work.

Comment: Since you are worried about performance why do you allocate the `BlockTextureData` objects? Not using pointers should make things more efficient.

Comment: @john there have been moments in runtime where memory consumption is huge. So the fewer objects exist the better. Im using punch of std::futures to generate objects and then they get copied back to main thread. Reducing the size of the objects is also important. Until i get shared openGL contexts working then i can probably remove most of the memory allocations in the RAM and move stuff directly to GPU ram from the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a helper function:

```
static auto makeBlockTextures() {
    std::array<BlockTextureData*, (std::size_t)BlockType::BlockCount> arr{};
    arr[(std::size_t)BlockType::Default] = new BlockTextureData{ /* ... */ };
    arr[(std::size_t)BlockType::Grass]   = new BlockTextureData{ /* ... */ };
    return arr;
};

std::array<BlockTextureData*, (std::size_t)BlockType::BlockCount>
    BlockTextures = makeBlockTextures();
```

or an immediately invoked lambda:

```
std::array<BlockTextureData*, (std::size_t)BlockType::BlockCount> BlockTextures = []
{
    std::array<BlockTextureData*, (std::size_t)BlockType::BlockCount> arr{};
    arr[(std::size_t)BlockType::Default] = new BlockTextureData{ /* ... */ };
    arr[(std::size_t)BlockType::Grass]   = new BlockTextureData{ /* ... */ };
    return arr;
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I head you can use enum values as keys for arrays, so i wanted to replace std::unordered_map with std::array.

What's meant by this is that you `static_cast` to the underlying type to get the index in the array.

Your syntax in `block.cpp` is simply wrong though:

```
std::array<BlockTextureData*, static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockCount)> BlockTextures[static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockType_Default)] = new BlockTextureData{"UV","UV","UV","UV","UV", "UV"};
```

declares a new variable `BlockTextures` that is a fixed size array of `std::array<BlockTextureData*, 3>` and is equivalent to

```
std::array<BlockTextureData*, 3> BlockTextures[1];
```

plus the attempted initialization with the dynamically allocated `BlockTextureData` object which is invalid here.

You'd need to go with

```
std::array<BlockTextureData*, static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockCount)> BlockTextures {
    nullptr,
    new BlockTextureData{"UV","UV","UV","UV","UV", "UV"},
    new BlockTextureData{"GrassTop","GrassBottom","GrassSide","GrassSide","GrassSide", "GrassSide"}
};
```

or

```
std::array<BlockTextureData*, static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockCount)> BlockTextures {};

void init()
{
    blockTextures[static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockType_Default)] = new BlockTextureData{"UV","UV","UV","UV","UV", "UV"};
    blockTextures[static_cast<size_t>(BlockType::BlockType_Grass)] = new BlockTextureData{"GrassTop","GrassBottom","GrassSide","GrassSide","GrassSide", "GrassSide"};
}
```

instead to make your code work.

It would be preferrable to implement a wrapper class for convenience, to avoid having to do the casting manually on every access.

The following is a wrapper for `std::array` that has a `[]` operator that works similar to the one of `std::unordered_map`.

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

enum class BlockType : uint8_t {
    BlockType_Air = 0,
    BlockType_Default = 1,
    BlockType_Grass = 2,
    BlockCount
};

struct BlockTextureData {
    std::string top;
    std::string bottom;
    std::string left;
    std::string right;
    std::string front;
    std::string back;
};

template<class Value>
class OptimizedBlockTypeMap
{
    std::array<Value, static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<BlockType>>(BlockType::BlockCount)> m_mapping;
public:
    using key_type = BlockType;
    using mapped_type = Value;

    constexpr OptimizedBlockTypeMap()
        : m_mapping{}
    {
    }

    OptimizedBlockTypeMap(std::array<Value, static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<BlockType>>(BlockType::BlockCount)>&& source)
        : m_mapping{std::move(source)}
    {
    }

    OptimizedBlockTypeMap(std::initializer_list<std::pair<key_type const, mapped_type>> entries)
        : m_mapping{}
    {
        for (auto& entry : entries)
        {
            (*this)[entry.first] = entry.second;
        }
    }

    mapped_type& operator[](BlockType key)
    {
        return m_mapping[static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<BlockType>>(key)];
    }

    mapped_type const& operator[](BlockType key) const
    {
        return m_mapping[static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<BlockType>>(key)];
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        OptimizedBlockTypeMap<std::unique_ptr<BlockTextureData>> map;
        map[BlockType::BlockType_Air] = std::make_unique<BlockTextureData>();
    }

    {
        // note: initializer_list requires the use of copy semantics, so this won't work with std::unique_ptr
        OptimizedBlockTypeMap<BlockTextureData*> map
        {
            { BlockType::BlockType_Default, new BlockTextureData{"UV","UV","UV","UV","UV", "UV"} },
            { BlockType::BlockType_Grass, new BlockTextureData{"GrassTop","GrassBottom","GrassSide","GrassSide","GrassSide", "GrassSide"} },
        };

        // warning: memory leaked here
    }

    {
        OptimizedBlockTypeMap<std::unique_ptr<BlockTextureData>> map = std::array{
            std::unique_ptr<BlockTextureData>{},
            std::unique_ptr<BlockTextureData>(new BlockTextureData{ "UV","UV","UV","UV","UV", "UV" }),
            std::unique_ptr<BlockTextureData>(new BlockTextureData{ "GrassTop","GrassBottom","GrassSide","GrassSide","GrassSide", "GrassSide" }),
        };
    }
}
```

You may want to save on the extra indirection by using `OptimizedBlockTypeMap` though; size of `BlockTextureData` should be smallish; I'd expect the backing storage of the `std::string` member variables to take up much more space and those will be dynamically allocated when assigning values later...